# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)\delta(x-a) dx$.

Tags: integration, special-functions

> Evaluate
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)\delta(x-a) dx.$$

I suspect that I could create another function, let's say $g(x)=xf(x)$ and perform the integral which would just give $g(a)=af(a)$ but I'm not too sure. Thanks!

Comment: Is this function $\delta(x-a)$ any type of special function? I rarely see $\delta$ used as a name for a function if not, and such context would be absolutely important. (Granted names are arbitrary but I generally just tend to see $f, g, h$ etc.)

Comment: take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965989/why-int-0-infty-x-delta-y-xdx-y) for a similar question. Yes, the answer is $a f(a)$

Comment: Yes it is the special function area 1 width zero. So it just selects the value at a point, like a sampler.  It is used in study of signals and systems with LaPlace transforms. Commonly known as Delta Function. It is first derivative of step function. Such a trivial integral would not be online.

Comment: Subtle point: One has to assume that $f(a)$ exists (because, for instance, $f$ might be defined a.e. except at $a$, otherwise).

Answer (score 3):

The general rule in integrating over a delta function is:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \delta(x-a)\ dx = g(a)$$

Here your $g(x)$ is $x f(x)$.

Comment: Okay thank you, I just wanted to confirm if I could do this.